# How do I make YouTube videos fill up an entire screen when using dual monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, youtube, x-windows, fullscreen

I am using a dual monitor setup on Ubuntu 9.10 using the TwinView configuration in NIVIDA X Server Settings. My total resolution is 2960x1050 pixels, and my individual monitors are 1680x1050 (primary) and 1280x1024 (secondary).

When going into fullscreen mode on any video on YouTube, I only see a cropped version of the video on my primary display as seen below. This does not occur on any other video sharing website - they properly make the video to fill the entire screen on my primary monitor. To my knowledge this problem only happens on YouTube.

[image: Cropped YouTube video in fullscreen]

I would rather not have to manually download YouTube videos to watch them - I want to be able to view YouTube videos directly from the YouTube website.

Comment: Does [YouTube XL](http://www.youtube.com/xl) give you the same problem?

Comment: Nope, YouTube XL videos are fullscreen for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Advice that might help:

1. Right-click on the YouTube image and
   select Settings. Select 'display'
   tab on bottom of Settings window
   (probably the leftmost), uncheck
   "Enable hardware acceleration".
2. The Firefox add-on [Glazoom](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6489)
   might be helpful. It zooms to make
   your desired section of a page fit
   into the viewport and adds a zoom
   control panel to the statusbar.
3. Modify the YouTube link slightly,
   from
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx
   or similar to
   http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxx

Comment: Guess, 3rd point won't work for most of videos and will say embedded video is disabled

Comment: @UK: I don't understand - 3rd point doesn't use embedding.

Comment: No luck with #1, but #3 works. If there's no perfect solution then that will be the best one.

Answer (score 3):

I use youtube-dl + mplayer, though I don't know if that counts as a solution for you :-)

It also has the benefit of not using 100% of your cpu to watch a video...

Answer (score 2):

Using a userscript called YousableTubeFix (works on Chrome, Firefox and Opera) you can select your default video size and quality. This addon has correctly solved this issue for me.

To read more about what it does and the option you're looking for, see my personal page. http://sergiotapia.me/upgrade-youtube-with-downloads-quality-options-and-more-using-yousabletubefix/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen with *every* video?

Remember that some retarded people upload videos with huge black borders.

Moreover, if you are sure it's a youtube problem, consider switching to HTML5 and see if that solves the issue.

Finally, you have the option of downloading the video using [flashgot](http://flashgot.net/) and then watching it with any video player.

Comment: Yes, it happens with every video.

My web browser is Firefox on Ubuntu, so HTML5 video on YouTube is not an option (no h.264 support).

Comment: Then I'd say downloading them is definitely the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with other video sites and found that using greasemonkey user scripts to [resize the video player](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/03/ted-fullscreen-video-multiple-monitor.html) is a good solution. I haven't made a user script for Youtube yet, as their pop-out player works fine for my needs, but it looks like there are a few other people that have made scripts to [resize the video player on youtube](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=resize+youtube&x=0&y=0).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Totem which comes with a youtube plugin (the program called "Movie Player"). It is part of the default desktop. Apparently the youtube plugin depends on libgdata being installed, so if it doesn't work out of the box check that you have it installed.

If you don't care about comments this is IMO a much nicer way to browse youtube.